# Chrome Cookie API isn't letting me use returned values

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension which sets a cookie when users log in. When I attempt to read the cookie using the `chrome.cookies.get()` method the callback can log the results but I cant pass it out of the callback.

```
function getCookie (cookieName){
    var returnVal; 
    chrome.cookies.get({
        'url':'https://addictedtogether.com/',
        'name':cookieName
    },
    function(data){
        console.log(data); //log displays returned cookie in a object
        returnVal=data;
    }
    );
    console.log(returnVal);  //log says this is undefined
    return returnVal;
}
```

I tried using a couple different ways of passing the result but it seems like the object is undefined unless it is called from within the callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your callback is called *after* the main function returns. (The extension APIs are called asynchronous for a reason!) `returnVal` is undefined because it hasn't been assigned to yet. Try modifying your function to accept a callback argument:

```
function getCookie (cookieName, callback){
    chrome.cookies.get({
        'url':'https://addictedtogether.com/',
        'name':cookieName
    },
    function(data){
        callback(data);
    });
}

// Use like this:
getCookie("CookieName", function(cookieData){
  // Do something with cookieData
});
```

If you don't like passing callbacks around, you could also modify your function to return a deferred. If you have to handle a lot of asynchronous function calls, deferreds make your life a lot easier. Here's an example using jQuery.Deferred:

```
function getCookie (cookieName){
    var defer = new jQuery.Deferred();
    chrome.cookies.get({
        'url':'https://addictedtogether.com/',
        'name':cookieName
    },
    function(data){
        defer.resolve(data);
    });
    return defer.promise();
}
// Example use:
getCookie("FooBar").done(function(data){
  // Do something with data
});
```

Comment: It's a function parameter. Pass a function as the second argument to `getCookie`.

Comment: I tried using the first example and it threw the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line `callback(data);`. I'm pretty sure I'm not understanding the syntax of the `callback` variable. Am I supposed to make a callback function within `getCookie` and if so why do i need to define it as something being passed to `getCookie`?

Comment: Edited my answer to include a sample usage.